# match string from end on TextFSM

Tags: networking, python-textfsm

Would like match output from end of line to white space

netmgmt@CCC-CC-CCC-RE1> show lldp neighbors 
Local Interface    Parent Interface    Chassis Id          Port info          System Name
xe-11/3/0          ae2                 00:23:9c:d5:7f:c0   295                BAZ-CPR01-RE1
xe-10/3/0          ae2                 00:23:9c:d5:7f:c0   306                BAZ-CPR01-RE1
xe-8/3/0           ae1                 00:23:9c:dd:a7:c0   xe-10/3/0          UKW-CPR02-RE1
xe-9/3/0           ae1                 00:23:9c:dd:a7:c0   xe-11/3/0          UKW-CPR02-RE1

I cant use left to string regex matching, cause i may see white spaces in port info tab, so i am trying to match from end.

I believe $ i use here for end, may be matching with ${variable} and causing problems.

I used regex101.com and able to match last word in lines using:((\S+\s+)$)

```
Value List local_interface (\S+)
Value ae_interface (\S+)
Value lldp_device ((\S+\s+)$)

Start
  ^Local.*Name -> LLDP

LLDP
  ^${local_interface}\s+${ae_interface}\s+${lldp_device} -> Record
```

Expected: BAZ-CPR01-RE1 BAZ-CPR01-RE1 UKW-CPR02-RE1 UKW-CPR02-RE1

Result : []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use $$ for this.

> To indicate the end of line (EOL) use a double dollar sign '$$', this
>   will be substituted for a single dollar sign during Value
>   substitution.

https://github.com/google/textfsm/wiki/TextFSM